# Failed to update data into the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I don't understand why is happening this error. my program something like this:-I have a collection of many data into the database and also have listed the type of session data. where "session "data-id is similar to my database data-id, there I change quantity using functionality. but when the last count of my loop to change my quantity property(I debugged that), then I found this error.

Here is my code :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Checkout(Order11 anOrder)
{
    List<Shop> shop = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Shop>>("shop");

    for (int i = 0; i < shop.Count; i++)
    {
        // var r = shop[i].Id;
        if (_db.Shop.Any(x => x.Id == shop[i].Id))
        {
            var t = _db.Shop.Where(x => x.Id == shop[i].Id).ToList();

            if (t[i].Quantity > 0)
            {
                t[i].Quantity = (t[i].Quantity - shop[i].Quantity) 
            }
               
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    // other code
}
```

Here is my output:

[image]

I don't understand what's the solution to this. I am a beginner. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what's happening here:

```
var t = _db.Shop.Where(x => x.Id == shop[i].Id).ToList();
```

Presuming your Ids are unique, this will result in only one item, but will return it as the sole member of a list.

Thus you don't want to index into `t` with `t[i]`. You just want `t[0]` to get the only element.

However, the whole thing can be made even neater:

```
for (int i = 0; i < shop.Count; i++)
{
     // Single() returns null for no match, the object for a single match
     // and throws an exception for multiple matches
     var t = _db.Shop.Single(x => x.Id == shop[i].Id);

     // ?. first checks if t is null, and only then looks at Quantity
     // if t is not null (i.e. Single() has returned a match)
     if (t?.Quantity > 0)
     {
         t.Quantity = (t.Quantity - shop[i].Quantity);

         _db.SaveChanges();
     }         
}
```

(Separate issue, but I'm not sure you need the `_db.SaveChanges()` to be called inside the loop. Why not just call it once at the end?

Comment: Actually, one further tidy-up would be `t.Quantity -= shop[i].Quantity;`

Answer (score 1):

`t` is the filtered list of shop, so its count is less than or equal to `shop.Count`, you can't use `i` as index for `t`.

You can change your code like below.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < shop.Count; i++)
        {
            if (_db.Shop.Any(x => x.Id == shop[i].Id))
            {
                var t = _db.Shop.Where(x => x.Id == shop[i].Id).ToList();
                foreach (var x in t)
                {
                    if (x.Quantity > 0)
                    {
                        x.Quantity = (x.Quantity - shop[i].Quantity);
                    }
                }

                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```